# save image path in MySQL with express?

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I am using express and multer to upload images. If I send the image to the intended folder but it does not save the path and it shows the error:

```
Cannot POST /api/imagen
```

```
const db = require("../models");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const Imagen = db.imagens;

let nameImage = "";
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "/uploads"));
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
const ext = file.originalname.split(".").pop();
nameImage = `${Date.now()}.${ext}`;
cb(null, nameImage);
},
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

(exports.create = upload.single("url")),
async (req, res) => {
try {
const data = await Imagen.create({
    titulo: req.body.titulo,
    url: nameImage,
});
res.send({
  mesagge: "Imágen cargada!",
});
} catch (error) {
  res.send(error);
}
};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share where in the code you've provided you believe that should respond to a POST request at the route `/api/imagen`?

Comment: add an image of the error / api / image is the path.